# R -- RJDBC not able to rename column in SQL select

Tags: r, db2, rename, rjdbc

Using the RJDBC library seems like you can't rename the column in the SQL select.
Anyone know a workaround for it?  I found this useJDBC4ColumnNameAndLabelSemantics=true for Db2, but not sure it can use it in R.

```
Select
a.customer,
b.customer as main_customer,  <-- returns as customer not main_customer
b.customer_email
from customer a,
     main_customer b
where a.customer_id = b.customer_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this -> [Column alias querying IBM DB2 using Oracle SQL developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46057953/column-alias-querying-ibm-db2-using-oracle-sql-developer)

For example, in my case the database name is SAMPLE and if I want the application to show the correlation-ID names from my queries then I use for the database-name:

```
SAMPLE:useJDBC4ColumnNameAndLabelSemantics=No;
```